# Sub-Folders in Newly Created Branch

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branch

Using TFS 2013 and VS 2012, I recently created a new "Main" folder under a project, then copied and pasted the Source folder from another project into that folder, then converted to branch.

After doing this the branch does not have the ability to drop down. If I select the local path, the folder shows up. But if I just select the Main branch from the Source Control Explorer it is empty within VS.

I have made sure that all my changes have been checked in and have no pending changes.

Answer (score 0):

After copying and pasting into the Main folder, converting to branch, and checking in, I still had to right click on the Main branch and Add Items to Folder...

Once I did that, they showed up, I checked them in and am now good to go.